# Full-text search doesn't return the row containing the searched keyword

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I'm experiencing a problem with my full-text search on a client's database. The issue happens only on the client's database, and I cannot reproduce it locally, so I think it should be related to the existing data in the database.

In the stored procedure, I validate the keyword for different symbols and then manipulate it and assign the result to *@SearchString*. If my keyword doesn't contain any blank spaces of quotations, I run the following query on a table with the full-text index on all columns:

```
SELECT [KEY] FROM CONTAINSTABLE([TableName], *, @SearchString, 1000)
```

The keyword I'm passing to the stored procedure is **I-MU-MUMB-ISC-2909** and after manipulation, I assign *"I-MU-MUMB-ISC-2909*"* to *@SearchString*. Even though the exact string exists in one of the columns, the query doesn't return any results. I used **STOPLIST = OFF** when I created this full-text index, so my problem should not be about stopwords. Also, if I search for **I-MU-MUMB-ISC-2908**, (string ends with 8 instead of 9) another row that has this string in the same column shows up in the result.

I even modified the select and used the specific column name that contains the keyword, but again there was no result.

If it helps, I noticed that these two rows along with few hundred more rows have **I-MU-MUMB** in one of their columns.

I don't have direct access to the server, so I would appreciate if you could give me some advice that I can test later when I get my access to the server.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer after a few days of testing every scenario that came to my mind. 
While checking the properties of the full-text catalog, I noticed that the last population day is *NULL*. I checked the log of the full-text search and saw the following error:

> a fatal error occurred during a full-text population and caused the population to be cancelled

Then I checked the error log of the database and realized that the database ran out of space a few days ago and it caused the full-text indexing to stop.
The solution was already in the log file, I resumed the population with the following command, and everything works fine now:

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON table_name RESUME POPULATION
```

Hope it helps someone!